# Accessing parent state within function called by EventListener in child's useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that looks something like this:

```
const [someState,setSomeState] = useState()

const onResize = (data) => {
    // do some stuff with someState
}


return <MyContainer onResize={onResize}>
  ... various children
</MyContainer>
```

The `MyContainer` component looks kinda like this:

```
const MyContainer = ({onResize}) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    addEventListener((data) => {
      onResize(data)
    })
    return cleanUpListener()
  }, [])

  // ...
}
```

My problem is that inside my first component inside `onResize()` `someState` is not up-to-date. I understand that `useEffect()` creates a closure and so i can only access values of state on initialization. I think I could add `onResize` as a dependency of the `useEffect()`, but this seems not great because then my event listener will be destroyed and recreated very frequently.

What i am looking for is a clean way to create a single event listener on component mount, be able to access state inside it's callback, and have it teardown on unmount. I have tried many things and looked around quite a bit and it seems strange that there is no solution to this. I am fairly new to react so i am hoping someone more experienced can point me to an elegant way to do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you want, but you can pass `someState` as a prop to your child component. The add that as a dependency for your `useEffect`, and pass that as a parameter for `onResize` if needed. As long as you are not mutating the value, it should be fine.

Comment: I'm aware i can do that. but in my real use case i have like 15 different state vars and memoized vars that i need to use inside this callback. This component also cares a lot about performance. Seems very un-elegant that i need to pass that many props around just to tell it not to destroy and recreate my listener every time anything changes.